# PyInstaller + Tkinter within Virtual Environment -- failed to built an executable in python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, virtualenv, pyinstaller, executable

**Question**

I have tried to built an executable with PyInstaller. A very similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528665/problems-with-pyinstaller-with-tkinter-app-on-python-3-5).

I am doing this from a WSL terminal on a Windows machine. I have created a virtual environment to reduce the amount of packages which are imported in my executable. Currently my script uses pandas, requests and tkinter.

I installed all the necessary packages via pip in my environment. And ran the PyInstaller with the following command (already trying the solution from the question above):

```bash
sudo pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=tkinter search_ucdp.py
```

In case i get asked this I installed the tkinter as follows:

```bash
sudo pip install tk
```

My problem is that I cannot get the executable running, no matter what i tried. It gives me the following error indicating that the tkinter module/library was not found:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[myscript].py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
[26040] Failed to execute script '[my_script]' due to unhandled exception!
```

Another thing i found strange was that the executable is generated without the .exe (but my guess is due to it being generated in a linux environment(?)).

The file is recognized as an executable and if i generate it outside the virtual environment it works. But why does it not work here?

**What I tried:**

- I played around with the --hidden-import from pyinstaller trying "tk" and "tkinter", but that results in the same error
- I also tried modifying the pip statements (same as above)
- relating to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975339/effect-of-virtual-environment-on-program-execution-in-pyinstaller) -> PyInstaller is installed both within the venv as well as globally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74157354/7976758 Did you check what was installed with `pip install tk`? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22install+tk%22+-tkinter

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in my Ubuntu WSL with system package `python3-tk` installed.  Command line used: `pyinstaller -F main.py` (in a virtual env).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did check the install as was recommended by @phd and the install was correct. Leaving it over the weekend apparently did some magic unbeknownst to me and i can now execute the script from the wsl terminal.

Comment: @Yonen No, it doesn't. You cannot install Tkinter with `pip install tk`.

Answer (score 0):

- Not able to reproduce the error, but you mentioned using  --additional-hooks-dir: Sometimes PyInstaller might not be able to detect all necessary imports automatically. You can try providing additional hooks to help PyInstaller find the tkinter module. Create a directory (e.g., hooks) and create a file named hook-tkinter.py inside it with the following content:

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('tkinter')
```

Then, specify this directory using the --additional-hooks-dir option when running PyInstaller

- And Also refer to the comment by @phd

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check this ASAP. Having not touched the machine over the weekend did some magic, and I can now run the script from the WSL terminal. A next step would be how to be able to run it from the windows machine itself. But i have to research this problem before opening a new issue here. Thanks again nevertheless!